# Weird javascript syntax return {unsubscribe() {}};

Tags: javascript, angular

I found weird construction in [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/observables).
What is going on in return section? Function call inside code block followed by empty object?

```
// This function runs when subscribe() is called
function sequenceSubscriber(observer) {
  // synchronously deliver 1, 2, and 3, then complete
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
  observer.next(3);
  observer.complete();

  // unsubscribe function doesn't need to do anything in this
  // because values are delivered synchronously
  return {unsubscribe() {}};
}

// Create a new Observable that will deliver the above sequence
const sequence = new Observable(sequenceSubscriber);

// execute the Observable and print the result of each notification
sequence.subscribe({
  next(num) { console.log(num); },
  complete() { console.log('Finished sequence'); }
});

// Logs:
// 1
// 2
// 3
// Finished sequence
```

Comment: Got me stumped. Dumping `{unsubscribe() {}};` into the console produces a syntax error...

Comment: It's short for `{ unsubscribe : function unsubscribe() {} }`. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that the code `return {unsubscribe() {}};` is a "Function call inside code block followed by empty object"; that is incorrect.

What is actually happening is that the function, `sequenceSubscriber`, is returning an `Object` with a function named "unsubscribe" as a property.  That function does nothing.  This is utilizing the new function shorthand you can see here: [Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Description)

Consider the code:

```
const foo = {
    bar(){}
};
```

creates an Object `foo` that has a `function`, `bar`, that does nothing.

The reason *why* it is doing this is to fulfill the interface contract that Rx defines for `Observables` as well as the `Subscription` interface defined in the [tc39/proposal-observable](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable#api):

```
interface Subscription {

    // Cancels the subscription
    unsubscribe() : void;

    // A boolean value indicating whether the subscription is closed
    get closed() : Boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns an object that contains an `unsubscribe` function that does nothing. As the comment says the `unsubscribe` function is not needed because the observer emits synchronously.